# sql stop count at a given threshold

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, count

I am generating reports in my system but some reports are returning a huge number of results.  To remedy this I hit the database with a count first, then in my code I check if this count is above a certain threshold (e.g. 2000), then don't generate the report.

This is fine in most cases but some reports have over a million results, this means it takes the count a good few seconds to return a result.

Ideally, what I would like to do is put my threshold (2000) into my sql statement, stop the count if it reaches this value, and return some value (e.g. true or false, 0 or 1, anything) so that I know it has exceeded its limit.  Is this possible in sql, so far I cannot find a solution.

Pseudocode: select count(1) from table while count <= threshold

I am working with java, hibernate, sql server 2005.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Eamon

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
select count(1) from (
  select top 2000 *
    from table
   where ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of running the query twice, once to check the row count and then again to actually get the data.  As a result, if you want to limit the report to 2000 rows, just do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2001
  ...
  from...
```

in the application check if the rowcount is greater than your limit `>2000` return an error, or skip displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

try something like limit clause? this page suggests how that could be done in sql server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserver/archive/2006/10/25/limit-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really aware of equivalent in Hibernate for TOP instruction, but even if there exists first you will have to retrieve the 2000 rows and then count it what probably will be slow as is now. So you can featch allredy 2001  row and then validate it in application.

But I think that what you should optimize is the query by itself. 
If in the query does not exists some outer join just specify index column in statement

```
SELECT count(*) from test1 inner join test2 on test1.id = test2.id;
```

888 ms

```
SELECT count(test.id) from test1 inner join test2 on test1.id = test2.id;
```

88ms

relation 35 rows in test1 match to 1 in test2;

rows 1252080;